# initialize List after Map has been rendered in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have a list and a map view

I want that the list should initialize only after map 'maprender' event has been called, is it possible?.

coz after my map loads I take the position and load the data in list according to the current location. in current case i cant get the location and list initializes with default values

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, when does the list get filled? Can't you just hide the List and show it in the maprender-event?

Comment: @andy I do not want to hide it, I want it to stop initializing until map even is done rendering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Simply add a listener for maprender, and when that happens create the list. Depending on your layout you might need to use a container as a wrapper for the list, so that you can add the list to that when maprender is fired.

Comment: so my main js have a map item and list item, how I can control that

Comment: @SirwaniMayur define the List in another .js file, in Main.js just have a container where the List first was. Then in the maprender-function create the List and set it to the container.

Comment: @andy, this seems good. haven't done before so will have to try.